# Adding HTML in a if-statement

Tags: html, loops, if-statement, script-tag

I want the html to open when the password is right and I have tried .js, document.write, .html, href, div, document.getElementById and nothing is working when it's inside the if condition but I need it in there so it opens when the condition is right.

```
<script>
function 123()
{
var pass=document.getElementById("pass").value;
if(pass=="password")
 {
   alert("Logged In");
   here is where the HTML code should go;
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You need to either use [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) or show some existing (but hidden) markup by using CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the html element in this page and give this element display none and when the password is correct change display example:

```
    if(pass=="password") { 
alert("Logged In"); 
document.getElementById("page").style.display="block";}
```